# What song has been sampled the most (ended up in the most other released tracks)?

Tags: history, hip-hop, sample

Being a drum and bass and hip hop fan, I'm quite familiar with the [*Amen Break*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwQLk7NcpO4)
and [*Funky Drummer*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoQ4AtsFWVM&feature=player_detailpage#t=321).

Is one of these the most sampled sound of all time (in terms of then being incorporated into other released records), or is it something else? As samples should go through legal clearance, the information should be out there, somewhere...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This article](http://www.theverge.com/2014/2/25/5445056/this-is-the-most-sampled-song-in-history-fab-5-freddy) says that the most sampled song of all-time is "Change the Beat" by Fab 5 Freddy:

> According to the [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p01sn5gv), though, one song has proven particularly popular among DJs and musicians: "Change the Beat," by Fab 5 Freddy.
>
> According to the site Who Sampled, "Change the Beat" has been featured in [nearly 1,300 songs](http://www.whosampled.com/Beside/Change-the-Beat-(Female-Version)/sampled/), including "Boyz-N-The-Hood" by Eazy-E and last year's "Thrift Shop", making it the most sampled song of all time.

Comment: whosampled.com actually has a top 100 most sampled for their database: http://www.whosampled.com/most-sampled-tracks/